# How can a Wondrous Item be made lighter?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I want to give my familiar a Healing Belt (along with a Pearl of Speech so that it can say the command word), so that it can save our butts if it comes down to it (and perhaps hurt that mean ghoul a bit). The problem is that even though size isn't generally a problem for magic items (I saw somewhere that items generally adjust their size to the wearer if needed), nothing is said about weight.

But a Healing Belt weighs 1 lb (0.5 Kg), and my familiar is so small it can't fly with such a load. (The maximum a Diminutive creature with 1 Str can fly with is 0.75 lb or 0.375 Kg).

I'd like to have a Healing Cordelet (some sort of very light string with the same power as a Healing Belt).

Is it possible to modify the stated materials/weight of a Wondrous Item? How much does it cost?

Answer (score 8):

## Worn magic items *do* resize

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* on Size and Magic Items says

> When an article of magic clothing or jewelry is discovered, most of the time size shouldn’t be an issue. Many magic garments are made to be easily adjustable, or they adjust themselves magically to the wearer. As a rule, size should not keep overweight characters, characters of various genders, or characters of various kinds from using magic items. (213)

...And the DM really *should* rule that magic items that change size to fit their wearers *also* change weight so their wearers can wear the items and still move.

Extrapolating from how armor weight changes based on the size of the creature the armor's made for ([Armor for Unusual Creatures](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/armor.htm#armorForUnusualCreatures) on *Player's Handbook* 123), a *healing belt* (*MIC* 110) (750 gp; 1 lb.) should weigh only 0.1 lbs. when it resizes to fit a Diminutive creature (like a [bat](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/bat.htm) or [toad](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/toad.htm)).

Beyond this, with DM approval a *healing belt* could—instead or in addition—be made from a special material lighter than its normal material, but materials lighter than the *belt*'s traditional leather are difficult to find. (For example, leafweave (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 20) is said to be lighter than leather but the weight of armor made from that special material isn't reduced.)

Note that the more difficult task than acquiring such an item is convincing the DM that, even if the creature's given the ability to utter the command word by a *pearl of speech* (*MIC* 118) (600 gp; 0 lbs.), the nonhumanoid Diminutive creature can benefit from the item in the first place. The DM may rule the creature just can't wear a belt. The Random Encounters: Wild Life Web column ["Tricks and Training for D&D Animals"](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112005822/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20031125a) says some animals can use a "belt or strap worn in front of or over the haunches," but ask the DM if that includes the creature in question.

This may mean commissioning a custom double-price *slotless* version of the *healing belt*—an [*ioun stone*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#iounStones) (healing), maybe?—, which would probably be nearly as expensive as any special material version of the *belt* would've been anyway and eliminate completely concerns about weight.

Comment: http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20050927a

Not sure how convincing a source that is for saying familiars can wear magic items.

Comment: @Ariane O, I didn't mean to imply that familiars *in general* could *not* wear magic items, only that the DM determines which magic items a familiar's *capable* of wearing, and a strict DM can limit the familiar's options a lot. (And double-check *everything* in the Rules of the Game columns against the actual rules; they're among the only the Web columns to ever receive revisions, for instance.)